# Logout Component: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I clicked on the Logout button to logout it should trigger the function logoutUser() and logout that person.

**Now:**

```
const onLogoutClick = e => { 
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.logoutUser();
}
```

`<Dropdown.Item onClick={onLogoutClick}>Log Out</Dropdown.Item>`

This is without the dot this. Now the error message is saying that it cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

https://gyazo.com/0eb7d40e7502d6d7b625add8371264eb

**Before:**

```
onLogoutClick = e => { 'onLogoutClick' is not definded
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.logoutUser();
}
```

`<Dropdown.Item onClick={this.onLogoutClick}>Log Out</Dropdown.Item>`

If add the dot this it brings up another error message saying that onLogoutClick is not defined.

https://gyazo.com/31c79e167b0b1ed276ed000e3d87f8f7

Answer (score 0):

Both are wrong.

Function components don't have `this`. See here how props are used inside such a component: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Correct would be

```js
const Navigationbar = ({logoutUser}) => {
  const onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    logoutUser()
  }

  // etc...
}
```

Welcome to react :)

Comment: All functions in JavaScripts have `this`

Comment: Yes indeed, I prefer to use a "export default function ComponentName" and then declare the functions inside simply by using the "function FunctionName(..)"

Answer (score 0):

Like I saw in the video, you are creating the onLogoutClick function outside of the component, try to move it inside it.

Or simple use the function inside the tag like this:

```
onClick={this.props.logoutUser()}
```

Comment: This still won't work, `props` doesn't exist against `this` inside a function component.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing class / function component concepts. Since you appear to be using a function component `props` won't exist on `this`, these are be passed in as a parameter e.g.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onLogout();
  }
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Dropdown.Item onClick={onLogoutClick}>Log Out</Dropdown.Item>
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: You can check on the last link, he recorded a video showing all the code. He does not use this "function MyComponent(props)" style by the way.

Comment: @FrederikoCesar `const NavigationBar = () => { ... }` is the definition of a function component.

Comment: Yes, indeed mate!

Comment: @bpdg no problem, but the idea of this site is you use upvotes / accepting the answer that helped you as to not leave questions open.

Comment: Yeah, still trying to figure which worked because still not working. To worked it out before I picked one.

Comment: @bpdg so you've tried my example code and it didn't work? Can you show the exact error?